# Exclude children of custom post type from search

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type of 'location'. I then have children pages for each of the pages for that cpt. so it looks something like this, "www.example.com/location/location-name/child-page/", each child page is using a post template of "location-product-services.php". So what I am trying to do is exclude from the search results the children of this cpt.

I am trying to do it by checking the meta data to see if it is using that template. I just cant seem to get it working. Any help would be great.

This is what I currently have -

```
// Exclude local product and services pages from search result.
function location_subpages_exclude_search( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set('meta_query',
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => 'location-product-services.php',
                'compare' => '!='
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'location_subpages_exclude_search');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
First I got all parent pages of my post type, used get_pages() grab them all.

Looped through each of the parent pages and ran another get_pages() for children of that parent.

```
function SearchFilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search) {

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => 0,
            'post_type' => 'location',
            'parent' => 0, //returns all top level pages 
            'post_per_page' => -1
        ); 

        $parents = get_pages($args);
        $excludes = array();

        foreach($parents as $parent) : 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'location',
                'child_of' => $parent->ID,
                'post_per_page' => -1
            ); 
            $children = get_pages($args); 
            foreach($children as $child): 
                array_push($excludes, $child->ID);
            endforeach;
        endforeach;

        $query->set('post__not_in', $excludes);
    }
    return $query;
 }
 add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I pretty much exclusively use the [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin any time I want to modify search. But to search programmatically, I think this is what you're after:

```
$taxonomy = 'location';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array( 'parent' => 0, 'search' => $query ) );

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Use the function get_terms to search your CPT, the 'search' is your $query (you might consider wrapping the search string with the SQL wildcard '%') and 'parent'=>0 returns only the top level.

Comment: its not a taxonomy, its a custom post type that i have set to work like pages instead of posts.